# Microservice HTTP port connection failure on Windows Server

Tags: http, windows-server-2016

We have written (in Go and Delphi) several Windows microservices, which respond to HTTP requests on specific ports in the 11000-12000 range. These are designed to run internally within the Domain or Private network of the client (i.e. not on the internet).

They run perfectly on all ***but one*** of our 50+ client systems, on OS's ranging from Windows 7/10/11 to Windows Server 2008R2/2012/2016/2019. The installation process for each of these services sets up rules in the Windows firewall to accept the requests to each service exe.

The one client system that they dont work on is running Windows Server 2016 Essentials. This is the only client system running that specific OS, so that may be a factor in the problem.

Even locally using a web browser on that system to query the services they dont work. The requests just wait for a while and then timeout: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.
However the same requests to the same ports at address 127.0.0.1 (localhost) work instantly - proving the services are actually running.
The mode of failure when the targeted service is not running, or if we address the wrong port, is different. In that case we get a quick "refused to connect" failure: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

There are no third party antivirus or firewall products installed on the system, which is only using Windows Defender with the normal Windows firewall. We've tried everything we can think of with the Windows firewall, including turning it off completely. Nothing we've tried made any difference.

We've tried using many alternative port numbers, but we dont get any success until we get up to the 49000 range and above, but we'd really rather not have to change from our normal port number range unless its completely unavoidable.

We've spent many hours trying to find any solution without any luck. We are really hoping that some bright person out there has some idea that will lead to finding the cause of the problem.

Comment: Out of interest, does the server have the Direct Access role in single NIC mode?  Thinking being, that a command such as:
`Set-NetNatTransitionConfiguration –IPv4AddressPortPool @("10.0.0.1, 6001-10950", "10.0.0.1, 12050-47000")`
Where 10.0.0.1 is your IP, can you want to exclude the range: `11000-12000`.

Comment: Thank you. This has been very helpful. I had no idea DirectAccess or NAT64 existed.

Comment: Researching based on your input, I found Get-NetNatTransitionConfiguration which does indicate that DirectAccess has ports 6001 to 47000 configured.
However I dont think this server is using it, as the Remote Access Management Console does not seem to be set up. Maybe this is just the default configuration for WS 2106 Essentials?

Comment: @HelpingHand In your suggested command: Set-NetNatTransitionConfiguration –IPv4AddressPortPool @("10.0.0.1, 6001-10950", "10.0.0.1, 12050-47000")  you specified a port range from 10950 to 12050, which is wider that the range 11000-12000 that I indicated. What is the reason for the wider range you have suggested?

Comment: I figured leave 50 either side.

Comment: I wonder if the following PS commands could prove it:
`$Listener = [System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener]10999;$Listener.Start();`
Check it's listening with `Get-NetTcpConnection -State Listen -LocalPort 10999`.  Then try connecting over `127.0.0.1` and then the IP. E.g. `Test-NetConnection -Port 10999 -Verbose -ComputerName 127.0.0.1`, followed by `Test-NetConnection -Port 10999 -Verbose -ComputerName <IP>`. You can run: `$Listener.Stop()` to stop PowerShell from listening.

Comment: Thanks for you help @HelpingHand. I ran the Set-NetNatTransitionConfiguration command and the problem is fixed (see answer below)

Comment: Glad it helped. It’s a silent killer that one, made worse by the fact that loopback works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As identified by @HelpingHand in his comments on the original question, the problem was Windows DirectAccess.

DirectAccess wasn't being used by the client, but Windows Server Essentials came with it preconfigured to allocate all the ports from 6001-47000. This was confirmed by the PowerShell command

```
Get-NetNatTransitionConfiguration
```

which gave the following result:

```
InstanceName        : DirectAccess
PolicyStore         : PersistentStore
State               : Enabled
TcpMappingTimeout   : 7200
InboundInterface    :
OutboundInterface   : {Ethernet}
PrefixMapping       : {fd3b:4e13:1a52:7777::/96,0.0.0.0/0}
IPv4AddressPortPool : {192.168.1.10,6001-47000}

InstanceName        : DirectAccess
PolicyStore         : ActiveStore
State               : Enabled
TcpMappingTimeout   : 7200
InboundInterface    :
OutboundInterface   : {Ethernet}
PrefixMapping       : {fd3b:4e13:1a52:7777::/96,0.0.0.0/0}
IPv4AddressPortPool : {192.168.1.10,6001-47000}
```

I ran the PowerShell command

```
Set-NetNatTransitionConfiguration –IPv4AddressPortPool @("192.168.1.10, 6001-10950", "192.168.1.10, 12050-47000")
```

which changed the port allocations for DirectAccess to leave the gap I needed for our services, and then the ports just stared working immediately. I didn't even have to restart anything.

Thanks for your help @HelpingHand